# Error while connecting to the ftp server

Tags: ftp

I am getting stuck while connecting to the ftp server.
I have Installed vsftpd and try `ftps`, `ftp-ssl`.

```
ERROR:
534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
SSL not available
534 Policy requires SSL.
Login failed.
Remote system type is Windows_NT.
```

The client has installed ftps.So,I have tried with `ftp-ssl` to connent to ftp server but, It gives me above error.Please,tell me why this stuck happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clearly says that the server does not allow TLS connection. In this case it does not matter if the clients wants TLS, because the server does not want it. Which means you have to change the configuration of the server.

Comment: Meance, On my machin or the client machin?

Comment: You have to change the configuration of the server you are trying to . I have no idea if the server is local to your machine or some server out there, but the string `Remote system type is Windows_NT.` suggests that it is some remote server. In this case changes to your local server does not matter at all because you don't connect to it.

Comment: Ok It meance the client server has change there configuration. and The client said that, they have install ftps protocol on there server. So, How we will get it that there is no TLS? please tell me

Comment: If your client is sure that they have TLS installed then they have either TLS not properly configured or you connect to the wrong server. This server explicitly states that it does not support TLS.

Comment: Ok Thanx you will asked my client to check once.